# Ubuntu 16.04 default python environment in my user profile is Anaconda Python2, unable to run guake "anaconda2/bin/python2: No module named guake"

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, environment

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and for ease of developing Machine Learning and other AI programs using Python2, I installed the Anaconda Python2 full distribution.

I always use 'guake' terminal emulator which I find best for productivity. So I installed Guake in my Ubuntu and when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
/home/enlighter/anaconda2/bin/python2: No module named guake
```

I deleted all `*.pyc` files in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/` folder, but that didn't help.

I am guessing this is an python environment issue. The `/usr/bin/guake` script contains only these rwo lines:

```
PYTHON="/usr/bin/env python2"
exec $PYTHON -m guake.main "$@"
```

Can anybody please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: seems like the second line in the script is calling `guak.main` as an argument to a python call? That doesn't look right. Did it generate that on its own?

Comment: Yes this is the script that came with the 'guake' deb from official ubuntu software sources

Comment: Just try to comment it out and see what happens lol

Comment: @jphollowed the script contains only these two lines. After Commenting out `exec $PYTHON -m guake.main "$@`, `guake` command does nothing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't execute the right Python execute: `/home/enlighter/anaconda2/bin/python2` while you installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/`.

Use `/usr/bin/python2` as default interpreter or install in `/home/enlighter/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/`.

To install within anaconda python environment, clone the guake github repository and then build and install guake.